# linq string handling 2 chars in 1 lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I've seen some interesting ways to handle strings with Linq:

For example, to hide numbers in a string by replacing them with X's I can do:

```
string strNum = "Hello, my number is ... 3456c456";

string strHidden = new String(strNum.ToCharArray()
     .Select(c => (!char.IsNumber(c)) ? c : 'X').ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(strHidden);
```

Is there a Linq way to do this where numbers are replaced only if the current character is a number AND the following two characters are numbers?

There's a lot of ways to tailor the approach above, but I am wondering if there is an easy-ish linq way to do it with multiple characters at a time.

EDIT: added requirement for current character to be a number as well.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a regex, not LINQ

Comment: By `replaced only if the following two characters are numbers`, would you expect in your example `34` and `4` to be replaced, but not `56` either time?

Comment: You don't need to call `ToCharArray` in your example since string implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @Rawling. Yeah, that's what I intended to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the interpretation in my comment, you can do this with LINQ:

```
string strHidden = new String(Enumerable.Range(0, strNum.Length)
    .Select(i => 
        char.IsNumber(strNum[i]) && 
        Enumerable.Range(i+1,2).All(j => j < strNum.Length && char.IsNumber(strNum[j]))
            ? 'X'
            : strNum[i])
    .ToArray());
```

Regular expression alternative:

```
var strHidden = Regex.Replace(strNum, @"\d(?=\d{2})", "X");
```

Much nicer, no?

Comment: Much nicer regex; removing mine

Comment: Today I learned that `Regex.Replace` with a look_behind_ will replace a match even if an earlier replacement renders the match no longer true. (So if you modify this to replace digits _preceeded_ by two digits, it'll replace both the third and 4th, 5th... digits in a group.)

Comment: @Marc Not really nicer, just solving a different problem :)

Comment: yes, but I think yours is closer to the (rather open-to-interpretation) "specification" (for want of a better word)

Comment: Learned several things here: (1) looping in lambda using Enumerable.Range(), (2) that I am probably going to have to break down and learn Regex, (3) booleans using All(), and (4) to write less ambiguous specs ;) Thanks, Rawling!